# How to start @KafkaListener based on start flag

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to start my KafkaListener only when a flag is set to true.

```
@Component
public class KafkaTopicConsumer {

//Somehow wrap the listener to only start when a property value is set to true

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{@consumerTopic}", groupId = "#{@groupName}")
public void consumeMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Consumed message from topic: {} with message: {}", message.topic(), message);
}
```

Is there a way to only make sure the listener is started when said a property such as start.consumer property is set to true? I don't want the listener starting every time the application is started only when I specify that I want it to be started. Is there a good way to approach this use case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ConditionalsBeans with a property

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(
  value="my.custom.flag", 
  havingValue = "true")
public KafkaListener kafkaListener{
 .....
}
```

Conditional beans allow you start a bean based on properties or custom conditions.
[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)

Comment: Awesome thank you! I will be sure to circle back once I'm able to run and test this and see if I need further information and mark it as an answer!

Comment: In my opinion this is the best approach.

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to set `autoStartup` to `false` and give your container a name. Then you need to start it manually based on a flag using `@EventListener`.

```java
@Component
public class KafkaTopicConsumer {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @Value("${start.consumer}")
    private boolean shouldStart;

    @KafkaListener(id = "myListener", autoStartup = "false", topics = "#{@consumerTopic}", groupId = "#{@groupName}")
    public void consumeMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Consumed message from topic: {} with message: {}", message.topic(), message);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onStarted(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
        if (shouldStart) {
            MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myListener");
            listenerContainer.start();    
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `@EventListener` will make sure containers are properly loaded, if you use `@PostConstruct` it probably won't work.

**EDIT**:

Added the actual reading of the property using the `@Value` annotation.

**Note:** This approach has the added flexibility of allowing the `start` and `stop` methods to also be called dynamically (using JMX for example) with just a few changes. This facilitates the scenario where we want to disable a consumer and enable it later without restarting the application.

Another good approach, as correctly stated in [@Makoton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62158307/1220802), is to use `@ConditionalOnProperty`. Just to note that in your example, you can use it with `@Component` instead of defining the `@Bean` manually.

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "start.consumer",
        havingValue = "true")
public class KafkaTopicConsumer { // ...
```

It all comes down to the level of flexibility you need.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I will be sure to circle back once I'm able to run and test this and see if I need further information and mark it as an answer!